# Get authorization code for transfer domain: is the provider obliged?

Tags: domains, domain-transfer

I need to transfer my domain. This domain was registered by others some years ago, purchased within package all-inclusive "website ready-to-go + domain + hosting". Now i need to move the domain from the current hosting to another, that allow to rebuild the website from scratch.

I read that i need the *authorization code* and i have not found it in the info that was shared at the registration confirmation. I see with whois that `clientTransferProhibited` is activated. The web panel include just some option to basic edit the website and manage payments.

I'll request the authorization code to the hosting provider via email.

My question: is the provider someway obliged to give me this authorization code? (If they don't give me the code, i can't transfer my domain to their competitors...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not stating the domain, nor even the TLD, which are needed information to write a proper answer since it depends on the TLD.

In the most generic case, yes the **registrar** is typically forced to give the authInfo if requested by the **owner** of the domain, as displayed in whois.

Note that your current provider is not necessarily the registrar, and what matter is who is the owner of the domain, so you have to double check first.

If your question is about a gTLD, this (from the central authority regulating all gTLD registrars and registries) may help: https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-holder-faqs-2017-10-10-en

> Your registrar may allow you, via an online interface tool, to
>   generate and manage your own AuthInfo code. If not, you will need to
>   contact your registrar directly to obtain it. Your registrar must
>   provide you with the AuthInfo code within 5 calendar days of your
>   request. The AuthInfo code is applicable to transfers of all gTLD
>   domain names, with the exception of domain names under the .gov, .edu,
>   .mil, .museum, and .int gTLDs.

You should also start by reading carefully the contract you signed with the provider and the clauses about transfers and terminations.